# How to modify the schema method for private route in mongodb/mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authentication, mongoose-schema

```
const contactSchema = mongoose.Schema({
name: {
  type:String,
  required: true
 },
mo_no: {
  type: Number,
  required: true
 },
creator: {
  type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  required: true
 }
});
const Contact = module.exports = mongoose.model('Contact', contactSchema);
```

When I am executing this server sent 200 status but data are getting added. Any solution?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any code that could handle data getting sent to the server, maybe that's why nothing is added...

Comment: @LucaKiebel when i remove creator field then the code works flawlessly